# Sorting problem with several destinations depending on filename-matching

Tags: sorting, command-line, filenames, batch-processing, matching

I'm currently sorting a folder structure of files with copies over copies of the same files.
Duplicates are already eliminated.

I have a folder structure of I:\Images\YYYY\MM filled with nef tif and jpg files.

I noticed too late (after sorting them into the new structure) that the sidecar xmp-fies were not written beforehand therefore not sorted along with the image files.

I've written the sidecar files separately from a backup, therefore they have different creation dates than the original images but **exactly the same filename apart from the extension**

All these sidecar files are now in I:\xmp

Is there a way of copying only the files with matching filenames into the different subfolders?